# Eclipse CDT headless build JVM error=1 on exit

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, eclipse-cdt, headless

I have a eclipse Luna CDT installed, and trying to set up automated build with the headless build feature. I have java 7 installed alongside.

When I tried to build the project using the following command, the project is built completely (both debug and release), but get JVM error before exiting.

Following is the command:

```
eclipse -nosplash -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -data <workspace_path> -cleanBuild <proj_name>
```

Following is the error while exiting (after build is done):

JVM terminated. Exit code=1

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-Xms128m
-Xmx768m
-jar /opt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-launcher /opt/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /opt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326/eclipse_1605.so
-startup /opt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 58001
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
-application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild
-data <workspace_path>
-cleanBuild <proj_name>
-vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
-vmargs
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-Xms128m
-Xmx768m
-jar /opt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
```

Any clue?

I also looked at other similar posts and tried different options.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem in the past, I solve this with editing Environment variables of computer,
you need to check that "path" contain directory of your jre/bin, jdk/bin.
If you make changes in Environment variables , possible that it work only after computer restart

Comment: I check the PATH env var and it seems fine. I have also tried both oracle and openjdk version of java. Both seems to give this error on exit. Also I run both eclipse and java in 64 bit. So that matches too. Right now, I am setting up a new VM to reinstall eclipse and openjdk java afresh and see if I still see issue.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my previous comment, I installed a clean ubuntu VM with eclipse LUNA and OpenJDK 7 and the error is gone. While the error is gone, the root cause of the issue is still not understood.